# Scroll to specific div/height after loading page if certain condition matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to a div after loading page means my starting point is that specific div  and curser should point to that div.i tried several things ,

```
if ($stateParams.year) {
    console.log("hiop");
    //window.scrollTo(0, 800);
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#scrollToChart").offset().top );
    // $(window).scroll(function(){
    //  $("#scrollToChart").css("margin-top", Math.max(-250, 0 - $(this).scrollTop()));
    // });
    //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#scrollToChart').offset().top}, 800);
    //$(window).scrollTop($("#scrollToChart").offset().top).scrollLeft($("#scrollToChart").offset().left);
    //  // $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, -1000);
    //
    //  //window.scrollTo(0, 800);
    //  //window.onload = scrollToChart();
    //  $(document).ready(function() {
    //      $('html,body').animate({
    //              scrollTop: $(".scrollToChart").offset().top
    //          },
    //          'slow');
    //  });
    //  //$(".scrollToChart").bind('mouseenter', 'scrollTo',);
    // //   $(window).scrollTop($('.scrollToChart').offset().top);
    //
    //  // $(".scrollToChart").ready(function(){
    //  //  $("html, body").delay(2000).animate({
    //  //      scrollTo: $('.scrollToChart').offset().top
    //  //  }, 2000);
    //  // });
}





   <div class="row" id="scrollToChart">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
             //content 
                         </div>
   </div>
```

But issue is when page is loading curser is pointing to  the location where i want to but after complete load page scrolls up. Any solution ?

Comment: Please provides the corresponding HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem , the problem was not logic. I was calling scrollTop on every state change on loading . And 'scroll to specific div' logic was executing before  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess') .So i set the timeout for that logic and it worked !!!

```
setTimeout(function () {
                scrollToChart();
            },1300);

    var scrollToChart = function () {
        if ($stateParams.year) {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#scrollToChart").offset().top
                }, 1000);
            });

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollToChart").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Its Working on click event

Comment: thanx for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do it your way, your commented out code would work if you used the id, since the div you're targeting doesn't have a class..

`$('#scrollToChart')` instead of `$('.scrollToChart')`

---

If you don't need the actual animated scrolling just use this one-liner...

`window.location.href='#scrollToChart'`

```js
window.location.href='#scrollToChart'
```

```html
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div class="row" id="scrollToChart">scroll to here</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
<div>stuff</div>
```

Comment: Here i can't use href

Comment: @PJ... that's why i gave two answers.

Comment: I used both using class and id .

Comment: thanx for responding :)